# Lunar surface brightness

Tags: optics, visible-light, astronomy, moon

If the Moon is visible against a clear blue sky with a lux value of around 30,000 does it stand to reason that the lunar surface must be brighter than that?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to  use the unit of luminance, cd/m2. 
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(luminance)) gives examples of luminances:
2.5 kcd/m2  Moon surface;
5 kcd/m2    Typical photographic scene in full sunlight;
7 kcd/m2    Average clear sky;
10 kcd/m2   White illuminated cloud.

These values imply that the luminance of the moon surface is less than that of the clear sky, even though the moon is visible against the sky. The lunar highlands are clearly visible against the sky; the mare are less visible.

Surface brightness does not depend on distance, so in the photo below the brightness of the moon can be directly compared to that of the sky and terrestrial rock. No correction for distance is needed. Evidently, the brightness of the lunar highlands (albedo 0.2) is comparable to rock.

[image]
Photo from [wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Moonset_morning.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the replay. However:

Comment: Thanks for the replay. However:"Surface brightness does not depend on distance".is dependant on distance if you use an online calculator. "2.5 kcd/m2 Moon surface;" How is this figure arrived at? Calculated using the solar constant and lunar albedo or measured at the lunar surface?

Comment: @Solon The photo is a striking and thoroughly convincing illustration that surface brightness is independent of distance, no matter what you may conclude from an online calculator. And the Moon is at the essentially the same distance from the Sun as we are.

Comment: @Pieter. Looking at the Apollo mission video cameras it can be seen that the expected light levels were very low and NASA had to get permission from the D.O.D to be able to use the then classified very low light level capable SEC vidicon tube on Apollo 11 onwards. Why would they need very low light level cameras? https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/ApolloTV-Acrobat7.pdf

Comment: @Solon For larger dynamic range, because shadows are very dark on the Moon.

Comment: @Pieter. "For larger dynamic range, because shadows are very dark on the Moon" This is true of course, but we have no actual measured light levels for the fully illuminated lunar near or far side. The Apollo 8 video camera though has a rated sensitivity of 0.1 to 30 ft.candles, and 100 ft.candles on Earth is rated as an overcast day, 10 ft.candles for a very dark day. I fail to understand how such a dim light could be seen at all from Earth, never mind being visible above a bright blue sky. https://www.honeysucklecreek.net/images/images_Apollo_8/RCA-Apollo-8-Camera.pdf

Comment: @Solon On the day side of the moon, the illumination is as bright as when you are flying in an airplane or in the sunshine on the highest mountains. The vizors of the astronaut helmets were covered with a gold film. How do you think it could be otherwise?

Comment: In addition, see this photo taken from the moon by Apollo 11, with the Earth in the sky, and compare their surface brightnesses. The moon is darker than the clouds on earth, but still comparable: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:View_from_the_Apollo_11_shows_Earth_rising_above_the_moon%27s_horizon.jpg

Comment: @jkien"The moon is darker than the clouds on earth, but still comparable:" Not to my eyes, it looks very dull indeed. The Apollo astronauts did tell us that the lighting on the Moon was very strange, and as they had been kept dark adapted all the way to the Moon it must have been very difficult to determine the correct illumination levels. When the next visitors go to the Moon at least they will have newer cameras so we will know much more from the EXIF data as to lighting conditions.

Comment: @Solon The moon is visible in the bright sky, because you are seeing both the light of the moon AND the light of the sky at the moons location in the sky.
The moon is roughly the same distance from the Sun as the Earth is, and therefore receives the same illumination. Therefore, the brightness for astronauts on the moon is similar to the brightness of light on earth that is not filtered by the atmosphere. That is, the same as brightness on the ISS, or on the top of the Mount Everest (if there was no snow there).